# javascript alert function not displaying mesaage

Tags: javascript

I was trying to take names from the user as input and tried to display the names so that the **first character is capitalised and the remaining letters in lower case.**
PROBLEM: alert function at the last is not displaying the message.
CODE:
''' var Name = prompt("Enter your name: ");

```js
var Name = prompt("Enter your name: ");
var firstLetter = Name.Slice(0,1);
var finalFirstLetter = firstLetter.toUpperCase();
var remainingLetter = Name.Slice(0,Name.length);
var FinalRemainingLetter = remainingLetter.toLowerCase();
var captalisedName = finalFirstLetter + FinalRemainingLetter;
alert("Hello, " + CaptalisedName);
```

Comment: `alert(\`${name[0].toUpperCase()}${Name.slice(1)}\`);`. This one liner should do the trick. You can save the contents of the `alert()` function to a variable if you want to use the capitalized name later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code is good but you have some typos.
a) function slice is lowercase
b) captalisedName in your alert have to be lowercase to

then it would work!

```js
var Name = prompt("Enter your name: ");
var firstLetter = Name.slice(0,1);
var finalFirstLetter = firstLetter.toUpperCase();
var remainingLetter = Name.slice(0,Name.length);
var FinalRemainingLetter = remainingLetter.toLowerCase();
var captalisedName = finalFirstLetter + FinalRemainingLetter;
alert("Hello, " + captalisedName);
```

Answer (score 3):

Few notes,

1. Javascript's `slice` function is lowecased.
2. At the end, when you alert the output, your variable must be the same case as you declared

Run the snippet below, to see the desired output.

```js
var Name = prompt("Enter your name: ");
var firstLetter = Name.slice(0,1);
var finalFirstLetter = firstLetter.toUpperCase();
var remainingLetter = Name.slice(1,Name.length);
var FinalRemainingLetter = remainingLetter.toLowerCase();
var captalisedName = finalFirstLetter + FinalRemainingLetter;
alert("Hello, " + captalisedName);
```

Comment: It seems there is an error here. alice gives me Aalice. This one-liner `alert(\`${name[0].toUpperCase()}${name.slice(1)}\`);` should do the trick!

Comment: I've updated the snippet

Answer (score 1):

This is the error message your code runs:

```
{
  "message": "Uncaught TypeError: Name.Slice is not a function",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 13,
  "colno": 24
}
```

Make sure you check the console when you run your code to see if any errors are being thrown, it can save a lot of headaches.

The function is not capitalized, so it would look something like this:

```js
var name = prompt("Enter your name: ");
var firstLetter = name.slice(0,1).toUpperCase();
var remainingLetter = name.slice(1, name.length).toLowerCase();
var capitalizedName = firstLetter + remainingLetter;
alert("Hello, " + capitalizedName);
```

I would also try to follow some sort of naming convention to reduce capitalization errors. In the example above I'm using the javascript standards, which are camelCase for variables and functions, and UpperCamelCase is reserved for data types and classes.

[Wiki for naming conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#JavaScript)

Here is the same code with const , Have fun learning JS!

```js
const name = prompt("Enter your name: ");
const firstLetter = name.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase();
const remainingString = name.substring(1).toLowerCase()
alert("Hello, " + firstLetter + remainingString);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could replace `var` with `const`. Sometimes this also solves the error.. Like this..

```js
const name = prompt("Enter your name: ");
const firstLetter = name.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase();
const remainingString = name.substring(1).toLowerCase()
alert("Hello, " + firstLetter + remainingString);
```